# LINQ - No data to copy to datatable error

Tags: vb.net, linq

I encountered an error whenever there's no data to copy to datatable. I'm not able to assign the copied datatable to my variable.

My code ResultDT as Datatable format:

```
ResultDT = (From d In MainDT.AsEnumerable
Group d By k=d("UPDATED_BRN").ToString.Trim Into grp=Group
Let check = grp.Any(Function ( r ) CheckOrderDT.AsEnumerable.Any(Function (x) x("ACCNT_ID").ToString.Trim.Equals(r("ROW_ID").ToString.Trim )))
From g In grp
Let ra = New Object(){g(0),g(1),g(2),g(3),g(4),g(5),g(6),g(7),g(8),g(9), If(check, "Available",g(10))}
Select ResultDT.Rows.Add(ra)).CopyToDataTable
```

So I try to change it to check first before copy to datatable but I got a different error.

I change it to - FilteredRows as System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>:

```
FilteredRows = (From d In MainDT.AsEnumerable
Group d By k=d("UPDATED_BRN").ToString.Trim Into grp=Group
Let check = grp.Any(Function ( r ) CheckOrderDT.AsEnumerable.Any(Function (x) x("ACCNT_ID").ToString.Trim.Equals(r("ROW_ID").ToString.Trim )))
From g In grp
Let ra = New Object(){g(0),g(1),g(2),g(3),g(4),g(5),g(6),g(7),g(8),g(9), If(check, "Available",g(10))}
Select ResultDT.Rows.Add(ra))

ResultDT = If(FilteredRows.Any, FilteredRows.CopyToDatatable, MainDT.Clone)
```

But still encountered an error - Cannot assign to ResultDT.
Can anyone suggest a better idea to cater if there's not data in the datatable?

Comment: Unfortunately that's the error message. I tried to use a simple LINQ query to filter datatable and assign it to System.Data.DataRow[].

Then use -
ResultDT = If(FilteredRows.Any, FilteredRows.CopyToDatatable, MainDT.Clone)

It works with no error. I think it has something to do with variable type. But the code where the filter happens can only accept that kind of variable type.